# Attribute::Handler's behaviors with use vs require

Tags: perl

I have a perl module implemented using Attribute::Handler

```
package FOO;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Attribute::Handlers;

use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(__RETRY);

sub __RETRY : ATTR(CODE) {
    my ($pkg, $sym, $code) = @_;

    no warnings 'redefine';

    *{ $sym } = sub
    {
        my $self = $_[0];
        my $result;
        print ("Executing subroutine\n");
        $result = $code->();
        if ($result)
        {
            print "You Pass\n";
        }
        else
        {
            print "You Fail\n";
        }
    }
}

sub foo : __RETRY
{
    print "Executing Foo\n";
    return 1;
}

1;
```

Now when I call this module using require, and call function foo(), it executes only the foo's print statement.

```
require "FOO.pm";
FOO->import();
FOO::foo();
```

Output:

```
Executing Foo
```

But then I do the same using use, it does the correct job.

```
use FOO;
FOO::foo();
```

Output:

```
Executing subroutine
Executing Foo
You Pass
```

Actually, in my code I am calling it using require and it's not working. 
Your help will be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`perldoc attributes`:

> The setting of subroutine attributes happens at compile time.

Comment: thanks richard, does it mean that I can not do it with "require"?

Comment: It means that, yes. `use` runs during the `BEGIN` phase ("compile time"), while `require` is a runtime function.

Comment: The "use" is exactly:   BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }  see, http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html

Comment: @jm666 - but for me this require statement is in the eval {}. So it's more like in run-time. can we achieve the same there?

Answer (score 1):

More exactly - the attributes are handled in the CHECK phase. So, when you eval/requere them got not fullfilled.

but, you can try the following:

```
sub __RETRY : ATTR(CODE,BEGIN) {
```

to force it. With it the next works, but maybe your mileage is....

```
eval { require "FOO.pm"; FOO->import(); FOO::foo() };
```

Comment: +1, this showed some hope but unfortunately it did not work for me :(

Comment: IMO, you know perl much better than me ;) so sorry, i havn't any idea now... here are some other perl-gurus - maybe they can help more. When you trying require the module, the module name is in the variable right? Therefore the compiler don't know it (it is not lexical) and probably therefore can't push it into the BEGIN phase...